# Quarkus: Using placeholders in @Path

Tags: properties, configuration, quarkus

With Spring MVC, it is possible to use placeholders with Path configurations. In `@RequestMapping("${myapp.path}")` the placeholder will be replaced with the `myapp.path` propert.

Is there an equivalent method for the `@Path` annotation in Quarkus? There the `{myapp.path}` part is interpreted to be a path parameter.

To prevent an X-Y Problem: I'm looking for a way to configure a path on application startup and looked towards the solution I've known from Spring.

Comment: This isn't currently possible. But you can certainly open a GitHub issue asking for this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is currently impossible. I've opened up an issue, so we'll see if it will be in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So, after struggling for a bit, I found this solution. Tell me if it helped.
I used the brackets in the @Path annotation (in my interface class service).
Then I specified what my id parameter is by specifying it with the @PathParam annotation in my method.

```
@GET
@Path("api/{myId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response findArticlePriceById(@HeaderParam("header") String myheader, @PathParam("id") String myId, @QueryParam("name") String myName);
```

You can then just send that parameter as a string from where you call your method.

```
Response jsonResponse = myService.findArticlePriceById("my-header", "133", "my-name");
```

My GET request will be : localhost:8080/api/133?name=my-name

Comment: That unfortunately does not solve the problem. I do not with to make dynamic paths with parameters passed in through the path chosen for requests.
My Goal is to configure the *static* parts of the path through the application config or system properites, which as mentioned above, is currently not possible. I've opened a github issue for that.

Comment: I looked up for your email and didn't find it. So I apologize if you felt spammed. Just trying to help here, nothing else. Have a nice day and new year :)